# how do i execute a program to the beginning when i enter a special value

Tags: java

Recently I'm doing a code which one of its construction is if I entered a special value the program will go to step 5(skip few lines) and go back to step 1.

```
public static void doall(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter VAL. -1 to end:");
    int val, a, b, c, count = 0;
    val = input.nextInt();
    PrintWriter output=new PrintWriter("Sum.txt");
    while (val != -1) {
        System.out.println("Enter a,b,c:");
        a = input.nextInt();
        b = input.nextInt();
        c = input.nextInt();
        int max, facto, even;
        max = findSum(a, b, c, output);
        output.println("The three original integers are " + a + " " + b + " " + c + " \n"
                + max + " is the sum");
        even = howmanyeven(max);
        output.println("there is/are "+even+ " even number(s)\n");
        while (a == 99) {

        }
    }
}
```

what should i put between this while(a==99),so if i enter 99,it will skip findsum method and evennumber method, and go back to the beginning which require me to enter a,b,c. All answers are appreciated.

Comment: We cannot *define* the logic for you, we cannot know what *you* want the program to do.

Comment: i edited now.sorry about confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize your integers variables to 0 first since they are in a local scope and won't be initialized to 0 by default.
I see that you probably attempted to do this at this line:

```
int val, a, b, c, count = 0;
```

However, only `count` will take the value 0 in this case, you cannot initialize your variables while declaring them like that.

What is possible is :

```
int val, a, b, c, count;
val = a = b = c = 0;
```

Then you can do something like :

```
do {
    System.out.println("Enter a,b,c:");
    a = input.nextInt();
    b = input.nextInt();
    c = input.nextInt();
} while(a == 99);

<rest of code here>
```

Hope this help.

Edited: Make sure also to assign an other value to your variable `val` otherwise your loop will keep on going forever.

Comment: I'm trying to add something after while(a==99), which when I enter 99 as a, the program will know this 99 is special value and it stopped execute and go back to while (val != -1) {  System.out.println("Enter a,b,c:") blablablabla .but thank you anyway.

Comment: Then you can do a condition like this: `if (a==99) continue;` which will bring you back to the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

It can be make problem using nextint() in scanner.
Try to use nexline() and convert it to int.
So if you want all in one line with ',' 
Use split on the string.
If you can enter number in different rows for example

```
System.out.Print("enter a: ");
  Int a = Int.Parse(input.nextLine());
  System.out.Print("enter b: ");
  Int b = Int.Parse(input.nextLine()); 
  System.out.Print("enter c: ");
  Int c = Int.Parse(input.nextLine());
```